# How do you line up regular text with section heading

Tags: sectioning, formatting, text

So I have this code:

```
\section{Thông tin là gì:}
Những hiểu biết có được về một sự vật, sự kiện được gọi là THÔNG TIN về sự vật, sự kiện đó.
```

How do I make it so that it's shows as that It shows as:

```
1. Thông tin là gì: Những hiểu biết có được về một sự vật, sự kiện được gọi là THÔNG TIN về sự vật, sự kiện đó.
```

I've have tried hbox but It doesn't work so if someone helps It will be graciously accepted.

Edit: Minimum working example

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Schola}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Thông tin và dữ liệu}
\section{Thông tin là gì:}
Những hiểu biết có được về một sự vật, sự kiện được gọi là THÔNG TIN về sự vật, sự kiện đó.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}

Comment: Should the header -- `Thông tin là gì` -- be rendered in **bold-face**?

Comment: Yes, the header must be in boldface

Answer (score 1):

You can use `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
 {\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}  % the font for the whole set
 {\arabic{section}.}                % the section number
 {0.5em}                            % space between number and title
 {\titleaddcolon}                   % format the section title
\newcommand{\titleaddcolon}[1]{#1:} % add a colon
\titlespacing{\section}
 {0pt}                              % indentation
 {*1}                               % vertical space before the title
 {0.5em}                            % space after the title

\begin{document}

\chapter{Thông tin và dữ liệu}

\section{Thông tin là gì}
Những hiểu biết có được về một sự vật, sự kiện được gọi là THÔNG TIN về sự vật, sự kiện đó.

\section{Thông tin là gì}
Những hiểu biết có được về một sự vật, sự kiện được gọi là THÔNG TIN về sự vật, sự kiện đó.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you will need to change accordingly also the format for the other sectional titles you plan to use, such as `\subsection`.

If you don't want to boldface the title, you can add `\normalfont` in front of `\titleaddcolon`

```
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
 {\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
 {\arabic{section}.}
 {0.5em}
 {\normalfont\titleaddcolon}
```

[image]

I'd leave at least the number in bold face: a visual clue is needed for the reader to understand that you're starting a section.

Answer (score 0):

(I updated this answer after learning that paragraph-level headers should be rendered in bold-face.)

I'd like to suggest that you replace `\section` with `\paragraph`, as the `\paragraph` command is set to produce "run-in" headers. As the code below the following screenshot shows, 2 types of (overall minor) adjustments are needed to get the desired format.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Schola}

% 1. Show paragraph-level numbers as 1, 2, etc:
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph}}
% 2. Add "dot" after paragraph number (see "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.)
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\paragraph@cntformat{\theparagraph.\space}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Thông tin và dữ liệu}
\paragraph{Thông tin là gì:}
Những hiểu biết có được về một sự vật, sự kiện được gọi 
là THÔNG TIN về sự vật, sự kiện đó.
\end{document}
```